# Class design and object references

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Here is a very basic example of what I am trying to do.  In reallity there are more relations but not something extreme or memory heavy.

```
public class ClassA : ISomething
{
    public double property { get; set; }
    ...
    public ClassB classb { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : ISomething2
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyProject : BaseProject
{
    public IEnumerable<ISomething> ISomethings { get; set; }
    ...
    public IEnumerable<ISomething2> ISomethings2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The issue here is that I have to keep a list of `MyProject`.`ISomethings2` and then   `classb` property of ClassA to reference only an existing item in `MyProject`.`ISomethings2`  list. The hard thing here is that:

- Removing an item from `ISomething2` should remove all references to it (`classb` property of ClassA instances to be set to null)
- Prevent other developers setting `classb` property to a non existing object in list or a new user created object.
- Objects in `MyProject`.`ISomethings2` could be added without having to be referenced from elsewhere.

These classes are used for project description **not database** stuff. Like when you open a project file for an application. So changing a property in classB should be visible to all since it is the same object reference. 
Is there a pattern to achieve what I want without much coupling? Alternative designs/approaches are also welcome.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are talking about.  It seems to me that there might be mistakes in your wording.  For example, are you sure you meant to write "Removing an item from `ISomething2`" and not "Removing an item from `MyProject.ISomethings2`"?

Comment: "Objects in `ISomethings2` can exist without being referenced." -- obviously, if they exist in `ISomethings2`, then they are referenced. So, you probably mean to say "without being referenced elsewhere".  You really should be more specific and more accurate in your wording.

Comment: Yes I mean MyProject.ISomethings2. I'll try to edit it.

Comment: The names you choosed in your example make it very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a pattern to achieve what I want without much coupling?

Not really, since at its core what you want to do "when X happens, I want to do Y to these other things" is coupling by definition. Which also makes this a rather undesirable design for the problem at hand.

If I had to work with this, I'd start by looking to make the classes immutable (publically at least) and controlled by the project. If you can't set the `classb` property on the object, there's no way to set it to be invalid. Instead the project class can do that (along with validation rules, and possible optimizations like reference counting perhaps).

But honestly, I would try very hard to not work with this. Project here is a manager of the other objects. Forcing class instances to be in some external collection is gross and unweildly. Occasionally it's somewhat necessary (games especially do this), but it should be avoided where possible and used with care otherwise. Without knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve, I can't say for sure which bucket this falls in.

Comment: a similar example: you let user create wheel specifications and then you let user to choose for each car the desired wheel spec. deleting a wheel spec should leave car with null wheel .

Comment: in databases it is easy to solve though

Comment: @parhs - Just because the specification is no longer available doesn't magically eliminate wheels out in the world.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm assuming the language is C#. If it's Java, similar mechanisms should exist as well.*

- If you want to track changes to the properties of `ClassA`, you can use [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/240613).
- If you want to track changes to the `ISomethings2` sequence, instead of `IEnumerable<T>`, use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).
- If you just need to keep `ISomethings2` sequence in sync with `ISomethings`, rewrite the property as:

  ```cs
  public IEnumerable<ISomething2> ISomethings2
  {
      get
      {
          return this.ISomethings.Select(c => c.classb);
      }
  }
  ```

If this doesn't give you an answer, consider editing your question. Its actual form is very unclear because of the lack of proper terminology and cryptic names of your example. Also note that you currently cannot remove anything from `ISomethings2`, given its type.